my LED light strip wont turn off
/*
 * when its bright the lights will turn off
 * when its dark the lights will glow blue and green
 * when it is in between, the lights will turn red
 */

 #include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
 #ifdef _AVR_
 #include <avr/power.h> //reduired for 16 MHz adafruit trinket
 #endif

 //which pin on arduino is connected to the neo pixels?
 #define PIN            7
 //how many neoPixels are attached to the arduino
 #define NUMPIXELS 10 //popular NeoPixel ring size

 //when setting up the neoPixel library, we tell it how many pixels, and which pin to use to send signals.
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

 int photoPin = A0;
 int pin7 = 7;


 void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); //turn on the serial monitor
  pixels.begin(); //INTIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
 }

void loop(){
  pixels.clear(); //set all pixels colors to 'off'
  int lightRaw = analogRead (photoPin); //get the readingfrom the photoPin and put it in a new cariable called lightRaw
  int light = map(lightRaw, 1023, 0, 10, 0); //take the lightEaw variable and convert it to a value from 0 to 10.

  Serial.println("the current light level is:"); //display this message on the serial montior
  Serial.println(light); //desplay the light variable on the serial monitor

  if(light <4){
    //pixels.color() takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255
    pixels.clear(); //set all picel colors to 'off'
    pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));
    pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));   
    pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));
    pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));   
    pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));
    pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));    
    pixels.setPixelColor(8, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));
    pixels.setPixelColor(9, pixels.Color(255, 252, 222));  
    pixels.show();    //send the updated pixel colors to the hardware
  }

    else if(light <2){
      //pixels.color() takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255
        pixels.clear(); //set all picel colors to 'off'
      pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(8, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(9, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.show();    //send the updated pixel colors to the hardware
    }

    else{
      pixels.clear(); //set all pixel color to 'off'
      pixels.show(); //send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
    }
      delay(1000); //a small delay so the program isn't checking ever millisecond.
    }


what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

reduce your code to the simplest program that turns on one LED for one second, turns off for one second, and then repeats

This is pointless else if(light <2) following if(light <4) because it will never be executed. You probably want to swap the conditions for the case that light is between 2 and 4. It may not be your main problem though.

Come on, @jsotola, the subject line makes it clear that the LEDs do not turn off, and looking at the code it is obvious why. If you don't want to take the trouble to look at the post, don't bother commenting. The question is "why do my LEDs not turn off?" but not expressed in those exact words.

@NickGammon the question could also be how do I debug this?

if(light <4){
   // do something
  }

else if(light <2){
  // do something else
  }

else{
    // do another thing
    }

If light is low (eg. 1) then that will pass the first test and the other two tests don't do anything. After all, 1 is less than 4 and also less than 2.
You need to rethink the way you are doing your tests, possibly changing "less than" to "greater than" which would make more sense.

There may be more to it than that. The code in the final else block will execute when light >= 4. That code would appear to be designed to switch the lights off. Of course, it may be that the OP has not tested under these conditions and thus never seen the lights go off. It could also be that the code is faulty. Hence the note of caution in my comment above.

You would need to move stuff around. If the light > 4 then turn the lights off, if > 2 then show blue and green, otherwise show red.
